# How to recover my data

Tags: kubuntu, data-recovery, testdisk

i tried to remove/uninstall my firefox but unfortunately i lost my all data in my kubuntu system . I'm just trying to remove all firefox file from my root system but i dont know how to remove all this thing here i just upload all command that i used at that time.i also tried to recover my files from testdisk but its not working for me.
Please give me some suggestions.
thank you

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox 
   22  ps aux | grep -i apt
   23  sudo kill <process_id>
   24  sudo killall apt apt-get
   25  clear
   26  sudo find / -name 'firefox'
   27  root
   28  sudo -i
   29  sudo find / -name 'firefox'
   30  rm -f /home/ravi/ .cache/mozilla/
   31  rmdir /home/ravi/ .cache/mozilla/
   32  rmdir /home/ravi/ .cache/mozilla/*
   33  rmdir -f /home/ravi/ .cache/mozilla/*
   34  sudo rm -rf /home/ravi/ .cache/mozilla/*
   35  sudo rm -rf /home/ravi/ .cache/mozilla/
   36  rm /etc/firefox
   37  rmdir /etc/firefox
   38  sudo find / -name 'firefox'
   39  sudo apt-get install firefox
   40  root
```

this is the all command that was i used at that time after that ill try to recover my system using //41  rm -rf .kde/share/config/plasma-*
        42  mv ~/ .kde4 ~/ .kde4.old

Thnk you.

Comment: You've deleted `/home/ravi/`, which presumably is the home folder. Be  more careful next time, and make a backup, before .

Comment: Sir , how to restore my backup . i already tried with testdisk and photoRec but its not working for me. Please suggest something. Thank you.

Comment: Testdisk and Photorec are not backup restoration tools. If there is a backup, which you have not indicated, use it to restore. There is no magic abracadabra to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just restore your backup of /home/ravi ...

Because of line 30 - 35 you have deleted your home-directory. The space between home/ravi/`and`.cache/mozilla....` is the reason. rm and rmdir sees this as two entities you want to delete, Probably it gave you some errors.

Comment: Sir @Soren A , how to restore my backup . i already tried with testdisk and photoRec but its not working for me. Please suggest something. Thank you.

Comment: @AjayGupta backup you normally have on a external media, like USB, Tape or Disk ... Testdisk and photorec can only find whats left on the disk. Deleted data blocks can be overwritten if not the mount-point is made read-only immediately after files are deleted, and the programs cant recover your files.

Comment: ok....so is there any other way to restore my deleted file ?

Comment: Probably not ..